# A test against a string passes regardless of the value

Tags: postman, newman

This test `pm.expect(jsonData.payload.invitationStatus == "A");` works regardless of the value that `invitationStatus` actually contains.

i.e. `payload.invitationStatus = E` will pass in the test.

How do I get this to pass only if the value is A?

Here are a couple of examples of the payload:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "buyer": "",
        "error": "E",
        "invitationStatus": "E",
        "supplier": "",
        "terms": ""
    }
}

{
    "payload": {
        "buyer": "omitted omitted",
        "error": "S",
        "invitationStatus": "A",
        "supplier": "ABC Supplier",
        "terms": ""
    }
}
```

Here's the test itself:

```
// Setters
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

// Testers
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
pm.test("Invitation status is A", function () {
    if(jsonData.payload) {
        pm.expect(jsonData.payload.invitationStatus == "A");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unexpected structure");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your first line of your code in this question shows a comparison between values. Your test is showing a value declaration, not a comparison. `pm.expect(jsonData.payload.invitationStatus = "A");` in that instance it does not matter what the value is as the invitation status is declared as "A" in the test, thus no matter what value is set, it will be reset when the test is run.

Comment: @ViaTech I tried `===`, `==` and `=` all of which passed regardless of the value. I updated the question.

Comment: ah okay looked simple enough, guess not. I'm also guessing you tested the value of `payload.invitationStatus` in the `jsonData.payload` conditional. Is that set correctly as the value you want?

Comment: @ViaTech sorry I don't get what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `==` didn't work but this worked `pm.expect(jsonData.payload.invitationStatus).to.eql("A");`

[image]

Here's a good resource for other postman tests examples https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/test_examples